# One-time CiviCRM On-line Membership registration with recurring payment/contribution

Tags: civicontribute, civimember

We are looking to end manual reminders, as it takes an enormous effort. Thus, a rolling membership with annual payments (Stipe) via a credit card seem like the obvious solution.

Now. however, it seems as if it is impossible to link an on-line registration of a new Member with recurring payments via Stripe (interface tested and works) to an  automatic update of the Membership period as a consequence of the new contribution.

I tried to use CiviRules, but to no avail!

There must be a way to solve this, has anybody out there an idea?
We run: WP/CiviCrm 5.50

Claes

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible, you need to set the membership type to auto-renew required